# What is the member in the last set of this pattern?

Tags: pattern-recognition

(42,15,3)

(24,20,2)

(?,12,4)

? indicates the number I do not know

Comment: It would be good to tell us where the pattern comes from - otherwise, we may as well consider [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819101/how-to-solve-this-sequence-165-195-255-285-345-x/819382#819382) a good general case for, "It could be anything!"

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer:

The first term is greater than the second term by the third term raised to itself. Using a formula, the tuples are generated by
$$(x+y^y,x,y)$$
for some given $x$ and $y$. It is easy to check that the two given tuples follow this rule. That would make the third tuple
$$(12+4^4,12,4)$$
or $?=268$.

Note that this is **not** the only possible answer, but it does work and is at least somewhat satisfying in my opinion.